# Distributed transactions in Spring: JMS+JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, jms, spring-transactions

How to synchronize JMS and JPA transactions with Spring without JTA?
Ideally, both JPA and JMS should roll back if a failure (exception) happens before successful return from JMS transaction commit.
The case is for receiving of messages by a DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Message handling code stores to JPA repo.

Is it enough to have DMLC to use a JPA transaction manager?

Or should TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy with "synchedLocalTransactionAllowed"="true" be used to
wrap JMS connection factory?

That is how it was done in best-jms-db pattern described [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html?page=2)

I run the test from the page above, and they works well. However, I modified them.
They use DMLC with reference to  JPA transaction manager, and there is no TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy. That works even better!?!
Both JPA and JMS transactions are rolled back after simulated JMS infra failure. 
How can that be possible??

Test code can be found [here](https://github.com/vbartoni/best-jms-db)